# Specify the location where the npm packages will be downloaded using the NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, npm

I use the following code to install npm packages using NodeJS:

```
var npm = require("npm");
var conf = {
    loaded: false
};

npm.load(conf, function (err) {
  // catch errors
  npm.commands.install(["my", "packages", "to", "install"], function (er, data) {
    // log the error or data
  });
  npm.on("log", function (message) {
    // log the progress of the installation
    console.log(message);
  });
});
```

How can I specify the location where the npm packages will be downloaded using the NodeJS API?

I guess that somewhere in `conf` object, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've located the documents for npm-folders.  https://npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html

This looks like the method by which you can specify install location.  I will test and see what works and post my findings.

Seems that `prefix` field is what are you asking about. You can set it here:

```
var conf = {
    loaded: false,
    prefix: "path/to/the/folder/where/you/want/to/install/the/node_modules"
};
```

Comment: Yes, `prefix` must be used. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to know all options and its default values, run this in terminal:

```
npm config ls -l
```

You can override 2 fields in `conf`:

- `cache` is directory for downloading
- `prefix` is directory for installing